# Will a moving neutron produce a magnetic field around it?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, neutrons

Will a moving neutron produce a magnetic field around it?

I know that neutrons have no charge, so magnetic field should not be produced along it...but neutrons have a magnetic moment.

So why can't this magnetic moment help it to generate a magnetic field around it?

Answer (score 7):

The magnetic moment generates a magnetic field on it's own, even if the neutron is not moving.  This field will Lorentz transform just like any other Electromagnetic field.  More interestingly, you'll find that a moving neutron will generate an **electric** field in addition to its magnetic field.