# Why do neutrons have magnetic moments with spin?

Tags: particle-physics, magnetic-moment, neutrons

Neutrons are neutrally charged, but apparently they have magnetic moments with spin.

What is the intuition behind this?

Comment: what is a *spun* neutron?

Comment: Have you learned yet that neutrons are bound states of charged quarks?

Comment: bar magnet is neutral but has magnetic moment. This is not unique to neutrons. Also spin is not the spinning particle

Comment: @G.Smith no, but I think that would probably clarify a lot

Comment: Near duplicate related questions [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/477016/why-is-the-neutron-magnetic-moment-negative)  and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/397099/how-can-neutrinos-have-a-magnetic-moment-in-spite-of-being-neutral-and-elementar)  and [also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83086/will-a-moving-neutron-produce-a-magnetic-field-around-it).

Comment: Orthopositronium has spin 1 but is electrically neutral and has no electrical dipole moment.

Comment: @Cryo "Also spin is not the spinning particle " We don't have a mechanical model for the electron, but in every other way spin is intrinsic angular momentum.

Comment: @my2cts all I meant was that fractional spin cannot be thought of as arising due to rotation.

Comment: @Cryo Spin acts in every aspect as rotation. It's just that we don't have a mechanical model of the electron.

Comment: @my2cts fractional spin means that I need to turn the particle by 720, not 360 degrees to recover the picture identical to the one before rotation, if I remember correctly. This is certainly not like rotation

Comment: @Cryo I know that. Yet spin behaves exactly as angular momentum. For example it adds to the centrifugal potential, which explains the difference in the hydrogen 1s energy between the Klein-Gordon and the Dirac equation.

Comment: @my2cts, I don't doubt that you know more about this than I do :-). I simply wanted to underline that, at least as far as I know, you don't get to spin by considering rotations. Not directly. The path I usually saw was rotational symmetry->operators for rotations->Lie algebra->look we can have fractional eigenvalues->look this actually happens in real world. Perhaps I am missing something. Can one recognize fractional spin without measuring it? Probably can - by observing how many observable projections of the angular momentum (spin or orbital) one has: even number means it is spin.

Comment: An obvious hole in my projections argument is two electrons in a triplet state...:-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A neutron is a composite particle consisting of three pointlike quarks. These carry fractional electric charge which adds up to zero, so the neutron has no net charge. But since the quarks do carry nonzero charges, if they are spinning around inside the neutron then it is possible for the neutron to possess a magnetic moment while not possessing a net charge.

The fact that the neutron has a nonzero magnetic moment despite having no net charge while also possessing a well-defined radius were clues that it had internal structure (the quarks), which was proven in the deep inelastic scattering experiments done at SLAC in the late 1960's.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you